# 3 variable optimiser giving a runtimewarning using SLSQP

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, python-3.6, mathematical-optimization

This is my current code in python 3.6 to optimise a constrained 3 variable optimiser using a SLSQP method this is what I am optimising to an elliptical distribution.
[image: this is what I m trying to optimise]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def func(x):
    return ((x[0]*((0.2292 + x[1])/2)) + ((0.9-x[0])*((x[2] + 
    x[1])/2))-0.16)


def func_deriv(x):
    """ Derivative of objective function """
    dfdx0 = (0.2292 - x[2])/2
    dfdx1 = 0.89/2
    dfdx2 = (0.89 - x[0])/2
    return np.array([dfdx0, dfdx1, dfdx2])

cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[1]-x[2]]),
         'jac': lambda x: np.array([0.0, 1.0, -1.0])},
        {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x: np.array([0.2292-x[1]]),
         'jac': lambda x: np.array([0.0, -1.0, 0.0])},
        {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x: np.array(0.89-x[0]),
         'jac': lambda x: np.array([-1.0, 0.0, 0.0])})

res = minimize(func, [0.45, 0.20, 0.10], jac=func_deriv, constraints=cons
               method='SLSQP',
               options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 100})
```

the error I keep getting is a `RunTimeWarning invalid double scalar`
I don't know why this is happening

```
Iteration limit exceeded    (Exit mode 9)
            Current function value: nan
            Iterations: 101
            Function evaluations: 881
            Gradient evaluations: 101
C:/Users/bob19/untitled9.py:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in 
double_scalars
  return ((x[0]*((0.2292 + x[1])/2)) + ((0.9-x[0])*((x[2] + x[1])/2))-0.16)
C:/Users/bob19/untitled9.py:13: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered 
in double_scalars
 return ((x[0]*((0.2292 + x[1])/2)) + ((0.9-x[0])*((x[2] + x[1])/2))-0.16)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The above error I don't get anymore instead I get 'Inequality constraints incompatible'

```
runfile('C:/Users/Robin19/opimizer v2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Robin19')
Inequality constraints incompatible    (Exit mode 4)
            Current function value: -2.77024369372e+24
            Iterations: 8
            Function evaluations: 8
            Gradient evaluations: 8

fun: -2.7702436937183577e+24
     jac: array([  1.49413376e+12,   4.45000000e-01,   9.27040055e+11,
        0.00000000e+00])
 message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
    nfev: 8
     nit: 8
    njev: 8
  status: 4
 success: False
       x: array([ -1.85408011e+12,  -3.00597522e+12,  -2.98826753e+12])
```

Comment: scipy's gradient-check does show some relevant difference to yours and jac=False will converge. So double-check your gradient (and as the converged result is huge: check your model)

Comment: I have checked the model and changed a number but it still gives the same error

Comment: Without automatic num-diff it does not.

Comment: what is automatic num-diff

Comment: Read the docs what happens with ```jac=False``` (and run it).

Comment: I realised I had left out a constraint in the code